# Memory capacity of the human brain in bytes?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, memory

Is there an estimate out there for how much memory (in bytes) an average human brain can have? Is there a physical limit?

Comment: This is heavily subjective. For example, one way of thinking about this whats the longest series of numbers (limited to 0 or 1) that you can actually remember? It's probably not that long. Does that mean one has the brain capacity of a dozen or so bits? Or do you say that it takes petabytes of memory to simulate the synaptic connections in a rat brain and extrapolate from there? Have you already hit the physical limit (odds are you can't remember what you had for breakfast 5 Tuesdays ago)?

Comment: Memory is much more than "remembrance". The cells store countless information. Technically every single molecule of certain proteins can store at least a bit of memory. You cannot really measure cognitive memory in terms of bits and bytes.

Comment: Here's one fun way of thinking about it: Say that the brain stores information as a connection between two neurons, so a bit is simply whether there is a connection between two neurons. There are estimated to be about 100 billion (1e11) neurons in the brain, so that's  2^(1e11 choose 2) bits, which is some absurdly large number (way way more than the number of atoms in the universe).

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking in the last comment -- it would of course just be (1e11 choose 2) bits, which I guess is about half a zettabyte, which apparently is approximately the content of the entire www in 2009 (wikipedia).

Comment: This not a bad question I think. I agree that brain information storage is not easy to define, and probably it's not feasible to give a good estimate, but the brain *does* store information, and information can be measured in bits. Yes, you need to be a more specific on what you consider "information" in this context, and probably you need some type of "fuzzy" or probabilistic measure, like how much information a normal adult would be capable of recalling on average. But I wouldn't be surprised if there are some estimates of this, or at least attempts to estimate it.

Comment: There are quite a number of very similar questions over at [cogsci.se]. You can start [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/49230/what-is-the-limit-of-human-memory) and use the **Related** list of questions on the right.